# exponential sine equation $2^{\sin^2(x)}-2^{\cos^2x}+2\sin^2 x=1.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Find the number of solutions in the interval $x\in[0,\frac \pi2]$ of the equation:
>   $$2^{\sin^2(x)}-2^{\cos^2x}+2\sin^2 x=1.$$

My attempt:

We know that: $\sin^2x=\frac 12 (1-\cos(2x))$ and $\cos^2x=\frac 12(1+\cos(2x))$

therefore we can manipulate the equation and saying that $u=\cos(2x)$ then $u\in[-1,1].$

we get:

$$f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=2^{\frac {1-x}2}-2^{\frac {1+x}{2}}-x$$

If I'm right, if we take the derivative of this:

we get $$f'(x)=-\frac 12(2^{\frac {x+1}{2}}\ln2+2^{\frac {1-x}2}\ln2+2)<0 \quad\forall x \in[-1,1].$$

We observe that $x=0$ is the root of the function $f$ since $u=\cos(2x)$ then $2x=\arccos(0)\to x=\frac\pi4.$ being the unique root of the original equation.

Therefore $f$ is strictly decreasing on the given interval therefore the number of the solutions is $n=1$.

So I've been told that what I did was correct.

Can you help me with another way of solving this? (maybe not involving derivatives)

Comment: $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the only solution in the given interval.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $x=0$ is not a solution

Comment: What do you think about my solution, guys? Is everything alright?

Comment: You've proved there is at most one solution.  I don't see where you've proved there is at least one.

Comment: @saulspatz Okay, working on it, but the fact that I changed the given interval with my substitution is okay?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I read your solution for the first time. What is the relation between your $f$ and the given function, say $g$? What does the solution $0$ of $f$ have to do with the non-solution $0$ of $g$ ?. I had put a point against your post but I did not want to hurt you in your score and I got rid of it by deleting it. You came out winning because it was three points instead of the two you had previously.

Comment: @Piquito You're asking me what is the connection between $f$ and the function with $2^{\sin^2x}$? I told you if you note $u = \cos(2x)$ use the formulas i've given and you'll get that function of $u$ and What I did I changed the interval according to my notations... That's why they are equivalent.. I mean that's what I'm thinking and I've been told by many in comments and asked a lot of people that my "concept" it's alright and it's okay to use it.

Comment: The connection is evident. What is not clear is that the root  $0$ is not a root of $g$ so you  should clarify this point (sure it's easy to establish but you need to do it).

Comment: @Piquito  Done...

Comment: I wonder why your score has dropped to 2 from the 3 that you had. Someone has given you a -1. Regards. (the problem is that I see a red arrow as if I put this -1 which is not true).

Comment: @Piquito I don't know what you refer to..

Answer (score 2):

After calling $\sin^2x = y$ for $0 \le y \le 1$

$$
2^y-2\times 2^{-y}+2y=1
$$

so by inspection we have the solution $y = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \sin x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$f'(x)=\sin(2x)\left(2^{\sin(x)^2}\ln(2)+2^{\cos(x)^2}\ln(2)+2\right)$$

Comment: Yeah I think that's what i did too, man, just changed the variable and interval... can you think of another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $f(x)=0$ can be rewritten by setting $x=2t$. Then $t\in[-1/2,1/2]$ and the equation becomes
$$
\sqrt{2}2^{-t}-\sqrt{2}2^t-2t=0
$$
It's therefore easier to consider
$$
2^{-t}-2^t=t\sqrt{2}
$$
For $t<0$, we have $2^{-t}-2^t>0$; for $t>0$, we have $2^{-t}-2^t<0$.

Thus the only solution is $t=0$.